# use parameter when populating a struct with dataset c#?

Tags: c#, database, select, struct

I have a struct in a web service in c#. When I use "Select * from TABLE1"; in a WebMethod I get a fully populated struct. But when I add a WHERE clause, I get null in response. Why is this? I have searched everywhere for a simple explanation but haven't found one.

How can I use a `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE _id=" + id "'";` If I only want to retrieve a single post from the database it works fine, but not when I get a multiple row response.

Is there also a way of ordering a multiple-row response any way in c#?

Thanks in advance!

edit :

```
DataSet myDS = new DataSet();

   try
   {
       myConnection.Open();

       // Fill dataset with account data
       //myCommand.Fill(myDS, "userdata");
       myAdapter.Fill(myDS, "toplista");

       myConnection.Close();

       int i = myDS.Tables["toplista"].Rows.Count;
       toplista[] mytoplista = new toplista[i];
       i = 0;


       foreach (DataRow row in myDS.Tables["toplista"].Rows)
       {
           mytoplista[i].name = row["_name"].ToString();
           mytoplista[i].points = int.Parse(row["_points"].ToString());
           mytoplista[i].level = row["_level"].ToString();

           i++;
       }
       return mytoplista;
```

Comment: Do you need to iterate over the result set and add a list of structs.

Comment: It's very hard to tell without seeing any code. Btw, I suggest you use a parameterized query instead of the way you've currently got your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I understanding correctly that your struct represents a single tuple from your table? If that's the case, you should either be trying to populate an `IEnumerable<MyStruct>` or only getting the first matching row out of your table. Otherwise, what do you expect it to do with the rest of the data that gets returned?

Comment: So, this above works when I get all values, but not when i use a WHERE-clause in the select statement.

Comment: What error are you getting when you use the WHERE clause? Is it possible that you're constructing it incorrectly? In the question, I notice that you're missing a single-quote before the ID. As Jon Skeet pointed out, you definitely should be using a parameterized query for security reasons, but it might also help to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: The error is that I don't get any data at all, it returns nothing. It is really possible I am doing a lot incorrectly. This is how it looks, i think the quotes are ok: String mySQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test  WHERE _id= '" + id + "'"; I read about the IEnumberable<struct> that you suggested above, but I have to read more to really understand it. What is the difference between the IEnumberable and using a loop through dataset like I did?

Comment: I have to admit, I don't really have any experience using a data adapter like you're using, since I pretty much exclusively use LINQ to Entities. And your included code doesn't really show enough for me to make a very educated guess. Have you tried stepping through it to capture the value in your `mySQL` string and then see what happens when you run that same SQL on the database, to make sure you're actually getting something back?

Comment: No, I haven't tried stepping through anythingI am a real newbie with this. I just want a web service to use to test a application that I am developing in java, so I don't know a alot about structs. I thought this was the simplest way to get a group of data with a webservice. I have to read up on this and start over from square one. Thanks for your help, now I have a lot more to google!

Comment: For something simple like you're describing, I'd suggest you look at LINQ to SQL. It will give you a really easy way to get data out of a SQL database without having to hand-write any SQL strings. And rather than structs, most people use "POCO"s: plain old C# objects. Good luck... and be sure to accept an answer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks again, and I will look into POCO and LINQ!